# Meaningful Sample Size

Tags: sample-size, discrete-data

I have a set of 100 people each assigned to one of the four groups (very short, short, tall, and very tall). How many people's height do I have to measure to know the general distribution of people among these groups with, let's say, p=90% confidence. 
How about if we disregard the very short and very tall groups since few people are in those two?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work like that, "confidence" in the statistical sense has a very specific meaning that doesn't go with your usage of it. You can't make a statement that quite looks like what you're asking for.

You will need to give more information, such as a margin of error.

Assuming random sampling of the population of interest*, the more observations you draw from your population, the more precise your estimate of it.

[image: Plot of sample proportions from 20 samples of size 100 (left) and size 1000 (right), for population proportions (0.15,0.5,0.3,0.05)]

In this case your categories (assuming they're clearly specified) amount to sampling from a multinomial distribution.

As such you can calculate a standard error for each population proportion, or give a [*confidence interval*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval) for each proportion, or you might give a joint confidence region for some or all of them together.

At a given sample size, and a given population proportion, the standard error (standard deviation of the distribution of the sample proportion) can be calulated.

Similarly, at a given sample size and specified confidence level a [confidence interval for each proportion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval) could be given.

> How many people's height do I have to measure to know the general distribution of people among these groups

You need to specify "how close" in some sense you want to be (such as specifying the width of the confidence interval in absolute terms - raw percentage error - or in relative terms).

For example if I say I want to have a 90% confidence interval whose ends are no more than 1% from the center (i.e. the interval half-width, or [*margin of error*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margin_of_error) is 1%), then I can compute a sample size that will get me at least that for each one (even if we have no good idea of the proportion in each category, $p=0.5$ is a "worst case" so we can always use that.

> How about if we disregard the very short and very tall groups since few people are in those two?

The proportions for the remaining two groups will change, of course (and their standard errors and CIs as well), but not by very much.

---

* other forms of sampling than simple random sampling are possible, of course, but that's usually what people are asking about.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So how would you go about computing a sample size that will give you a x% confidence interval whose ends are no more than y% from the center?

Comment: See the article I linked in my answer [Margin of Error - Different confidence levels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margin_of_error#Different_confidence_levels). Those values on the numerator come from normal tables and assume you don't have a good idea of the largest proportion (so they assume its 50%, the worst case). You can back out the sample size to achieve a given margin of error. More general formulas (in terms of a good estimate of p) are [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/135755/sample-size-calculation-for-proportion) and .... ctd

Comment: ctd... ones that account for a small population (e.g. where you sample is more than a small percentage of the population) are [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/135755/sample-size-calculation-for-proportion)